# Using MFMailComposeViewController without presenting the view controller SWIFT

Tags: swift, email

I want to know if I can directly send my email via my "send" button without presenting the view controller to confirm the email ?

here's my code

```
@IBOutlet weak var body: UITextView!


@IBOutlet weak var MessageBody: UITextView!

@IBAction func SendEmail(sender: AnyObject) {
    let picker = MFMailComposeViewController()
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self
  picker.setToRecipients(["reobet@gmail.com"])
   picker.setSubject("Hello it's me.")
    picker.setMessageBody(body.text, isHTML: true)
    presentViewController(picker, animated: false, completion: nil)

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Chances are this is not possible. Users expect the Apple UI to send emails, so I don't see it as a problem.